# system.argumentnullexception value cannot be null

Tags: c#

I tried to do a filter api service with this query

```
create proc usp_filter
@name VARCHAR(50),
@lastname VARCHAR(50),
@pass VARCHAR(50)
as
begin
SELECT * FROM tb_users
WHERE
(name = @name OR @name is null) AND
(lastname = @lastname OR @lastname is null) AND
(pass = @pass OR @pass is null)
end 
go
```

which filters data from a table but it can ignore some or all parameters if it is required.

so when i send the parameters in c#, it only returns the list if all parameters are entered, in  case i want to send a null parameter this error is generated in the controller

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code.
>
> Additional information: The value cannot be null.

i tried to handle this error with DbNull but i get the same error

this is my method

```
public List<User> Filter(string name, string lastname, string pass)
        {
            List<User> users = null;
            cnx.Open();
            string sqlStatement = "usp_filter";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, cnx);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name ?? Convert.DBNull);

               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastname ?? Convert.DBNull);

             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass ?? Convert.DBNull);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                users = new List<User>();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.id = int.Parse(reader["id"].ToString());
                    user.name= reader["name"].ToString();
                    user.lastName= reader["lastname"].ToString();
                    user.address= reader["address"].ToString();
                    user.email = reader["email"].ToString();
                    user.pass= reader["pass"].ToString();
                    users.Add(user);
                }
            }
            cnx.Close();
            return users;
        }
```

and this is how i handled it in my controller.

```
 [HttpGet]
        public User Filter(string name,string lastname,string pass)
        {
            var list = business.Filter(name,lastname,pass);
            User user = list.Where(x => x.name == name && x.lastname == lastname && x.pass == pass).SingleOrDefault();

            return user;
        }
```

Edit of the exception https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKBrU.png

Comment: You should have gotten a stack trace that tells you the precise location where that exception occurred.

Comment: FYI, there's no point in checking for null with an `if` and then also checking with the conditional operator `??`.  You can reduce all the `if-else` logic to just the one line using the `??`.

Comment: You want `DBNull.Value` rather than `Convert.DBNull`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You input params on your proc need to be nullable. This would work.

```
@name VARCHAR(50)= NULL,
@lastname VARCHAR(50)= NULL,
@pass VARCHAR(50)= NULL
```

Also there are objects in .net for null values so you can change `Convert.DBNull`
to `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null`

`string` can't be null, so coalescing won't work (`??`). Best to write them as:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ?
    System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null : name);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastname) ?
    System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null : lastname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", string.IsNullOrEmpty(pass) ?
    System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString.Null : pass);
```

Comment: thanks but i get the same error, it is generated in the controller. i think i should use httpPost instead of httpget

Comment: Specifically, in this line of the controller   ** User user = list.Where(x => x.name == name && x.lastname == lastname && x.pass == pass).SingleOrDefault();**

Comment: can you post the error message as an edit to your question please? It could be a couple of things but need to see the error

Comment: I'm guessing one of name, lastname or pass is null, maybe even list... Just add a breakpoint on that line and check the values of them